# Emotion Icons Sprite Sheet?

Tags: css, icons, emotion

lately I've been trying to find a sprite sheet similar to bootstrap's but with emotion icons only (smiley face, sad face, etc), but can't seem to find one. Does anyone know of one with the css that goes along with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, try  [IcoMoon App](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)

then check put the IcoMoon Free font, it has quite a bunch of emoticon fonts.

Otherwise, you can download some free emoticon package, convert the images to SVG and then import into IcoMoon App, then the app will create your font set with CSS included